# Rectangle with 0-10 Digits

Tags: python

I'm quite new to Python and I'm struggling with this one task. It may seem simple but I really have no idea how to do it. The task is to make a rectangle using only 0-10 digits, with the numbers breaking to the next one every time it meets the selected width until it reaches the selected length. It should look something like this. I make it break once, but then the 'if' task is completed and the rest of the numbers continue in one line.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3
4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
```

EDIT:
I tried this, forgot to post it, my bad!

```
width = eval(input('Input width:'))
length = eval(input('Input length:'))

counter = 0

while counter < length:

     if counter == width:
         print('\n')
     counter +=1
     print(counter , end=' ')
```

it outputs this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
```

and I'm having trouble limiting the numbers to 0-10 only.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Comment: wheres your code?

Comment: Welcome! Can you post the code you have now? This will help others give feedback on what you've tried.

Comment: I edited it,should give you a better insight on it.

Comment: Sounds like a `%` operator exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're given the rows and the cols as input you need something like this:

```
rows, cols = map(int,input().split()) 

idx = 0

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        print(idx%10,end="")
        idx = idx+1
    print("")
```

the following code given input as `rows = 4 & cols = 9` will print:

```
012345678
901234567
890123456
789012345
```

if `rows or cols` are fixed then simple replace the input with a fixed number.

Comment: Thanks i can copy this but i would rather understand it.Care to explain what is map,int,.split,idx%10, i guess idx is a counter right?

Comment: Sure, so the first row is to read two integers and store the values in rows and cols variables respectively,  `input` as you know reads the input, `split` then splits the input according to a parameter (separator) in case of no separator is given the default is `empty space` map() function takes 2 parameters, first one a function or data type and the second one any iterator (list, tuple, or dictionary) in this case the input after split. at last idx is a counter and %10 is what did the trick (try to figure out more about this use of the modulo operator).

Comment: x % 10 = L <---> x = 10M + L, where 0<L<9

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate the help :)

Comment: @Daxon my pleasure

Comment: @LuisFelipe actually it should be `where 0<=L<=9`.

Answer (score 1):

```
width = eval(input('Width: '))
height = eval(input('Height: '))

n = 0;

for w in range(width):
    for h in range(height):
        print(n%10, end="");
        n += 1
    print("")
```